# Facing issue with the latest chrome update(84) to make default cookie option as "BLock third-party cookies in incognito mode"

Tags: community, liveagent, chat

We have a Chat button on our community page using which user can communicate with Agents for their issues.

User can use the community page in normal mode as well as in incognito mode. But with latest update for chrome(**Version 84**) to make default option as "**BLock third-party cookies in incognito mode**" ,

[image]

when user tries to use the chat from incognito mode it receives following exception

[image]

It works for all other browser except **chrome V-84**.
But when "**Allow all cookies**" is set, then all works fine in **chrome V-84**, from user prospective we don't want our users to go to this setting and enable this option and then use this Chat feature in incognito mode, please advise if we can update this browser setting using LWC while user tries to use this feature in incognito mode or is there any other way to troubleshoot this issue.

---

To check if user is in incognito mode we tried to use `navigator` but it didn't have element what we are looking for , when code execution happens through console directly it works fine but when we had added code in LWC component and tried to debug same, it returned following result.
[image]

Navigator :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible through the code to update chrome settings. Some of the things can be done though -

1. Companies got control over the browser(specially Chrome), so we can set the configurations on the browser through company network/security team.
2. Since community is used by customers, which we can't control. We can have a script to identify the chrome 84's incognito session, so that we can show custom error message page with showing proper navigation to update the setting/leave incognito.

**Script to check Chrome 84'th version -**

```js
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome/84') > 0 ){
   alert('I am in Chrome with version 84+');
}
```

**To check if we're in incognito or not - [Copied from - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57438917) ]**

```js
if ('storage' in navigator && 'estimate' in navigator.storage) {
    const {usage, quota} = await navigator.storage.estimate();
    console.log(`Using ${usage} out of ${quota} bytes.`);

    if(quota < 120000000){
        console.log('Incognito')
    } else {
        console.log('Not Incognito')
    }   
}
```

Comment: 'storage' in navigator isn't working for us when we add this script in LWC component, I have updated my question with details.

Comment: May be you can try other ways from the link. Locker is preventing that actually.

Comment: Looks like none of the options mentioned on that link is working for me.